# Storing assets in cloud and read them securely

Tags: ios, swift, cloud, assets, icloud

I am developing an iOS app that uses a large amount of images that are needed for animations for short videos. I want to save my application assets as static files in cloud and once they are needed download them using secure API call (either JSON, XML or any other alternative for that matter).

What is the best option for that. I have checked Parse, Dropbox, iCloud, Google Drive, but I am puzzled since I see only instructions for dynamic data that lets users access content they have created and not static assets.

What would be best option for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want an easy way to serve static files I would take a look at [Amazon S3](http://s3.amazonaws.com). You can just upload files through the online console and then get the public URL to those files to use in your app. You can also use the S3 API to upload files through your web service or iOS app.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for Parse (basically because it is fast to learn and develop), you can create a table with the images and change the writing permissions if you are afraid somebody could modify the table.

Another option that you can check it's the special Config table so you can upload custom files (zip files i.e.) and download them in demand.